# SQL, LEFT operator on datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to use the LEFT() operator in MSSQL on a datetime.

I'm asking because this is my db:

[image]

In a SQL query i want now to SELECT only this objects WHERE Rueckmeldetatum = a date in form like (2023-01-27) so my string comperable has no time just a date. But with this SQL Query I'm getting no results:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [KNR]
      ,[Rueckmeldedatum]
  FROM [Fertigung].[dbo].[Box1Auswertung]
  WHERE LEFT(Rueckmeldedatum,10) ='2023-01-27'
```

But normally or what i want to get is the 20th entry from the picture.

Comment: Column Rueckmeldetatum data type?

Comment: TOP but no ORDER BY will give you random rows.

Answer (score 3):

You should *cast* the datetime to date, then compare to a date literal:

```sql
SELECT TOP (1000) [KNR], [Rueckmeldedatum]
FROM [Fertigung].[dbo].[Box1Auswertung]
WHERE CAST(Rueckmeldedatum AS date) = '20230127';
```

Or, better yet, use this sargable version:

```sql
SELECT TOP (1000) [KNR], [Rueckmeldedatum]
FROM [Fertigung].[dbo].[Box1Auswertung]
WHERE Rueckmeldedatum >= '20230127 00:00:00' AND
      Rueckmeldedatum < '20230128';
```

Comment: ```SELECT KNR, SUM(DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,'0:00:00', Durchlaufzeit)) AS Durchlaufzeit, SUM(DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,'0:00:00', produktiv)) AS produktiv,
SUM(DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,'0:00:00', davonStoerung)) AS davonStoerung, SUM(DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,'0:00:00', davonAbwesenheit)) AS davonAbwesenheit 
FROM Fertigung.dbo.Box1Auswertung
WHERE LEFT(CONVERT(CHAR(19),Rueckmeldedatum,104),10) = '09.01.2023'
GROUP BY KNR``` 
Have done it like this

Comment: @Code123 your version is going to suffer performance problems. You have made the query nonsargable by using functions like LEFT in your where predicates. You also have non-standard date literals. I would follow the excellent example posted here.

Comment: I much prefer the second form - while the first is one exception where applying an expression to a column can still seek on an index, it [can still be really bad for performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/34052/1186) depending on statistics and data skew.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks for the comment, and much appreciated coming from a legend.

Answer (score -1):

You should use this instead of LEFT or casting, then, if the index is available, your query can use this:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [KNR]
      ,[Rueckmeldedatum]
  FROM [Fertigung].[dbo].[Box1Auswertung]
  WHERE Rueckmeldedatum >= '2023-01-27' AND Rueckmeldedatum < DATEADD(DAY, 1, '2023-01-27')
```

Also, make your query from the application parameterized.

Comment: Multiple problems here - your results will include data from the 28th at midnight, and also will fail in more than half the languages supported by SQL Server (since `yyyy-mm-dd` is often interpreted as `yyyy-dd-mm`). See [Dating Responsibly](https://sqlblog.org/dates) and [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QNaJc5xZ).

Comment: For the first note see [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bUinCcTt) - just don't ever use `BETWEEN` for date range queries, and always use `yyyyMMdd`.

Comment: I can agree with that ill edit my answer to >= and <